# GraphQL API how to repeat a query for different values

Tags: python-3.x, api, graphql

we use GraphQL API to fetch data in my work. this is my query

```
q='''{
  course1:course(id:12){
    ...CourseFragment
  }
  course2:course(id:13){
    ...CourseFragment
  }
}'''


fragment CourseFragment on Course {
  CourseID: _id
    CourseUUID: id
    CourseName: name
}


data=requests.post('url',q,headers)
```

and I am getting the data in json format. my question is what if I want to repeat the query for multiple course ids? is there any other way than repeating the course fragment part. I really appreciate any help or guidance on it. Thank you